# Python support for SparkRunner in Apache Beam

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-beam

Is there support for running python programs using Apache beam and SparkRunner?

The documentation doesn't seem to have it: https://beam.apache.org/get-started/wordcount-example/#apache-spark-runner

And when I look at the API reference
https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/pydoc/0.6.0/apache_beam.runners.html I don't find any mention of SparkRunner in there.

There is mention and support for Java I believe, but I'm wondering if the python support is there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no support for running pipelines built with Apache Beam's Python SDK on the Apache Spark *at the moment*. However, this work is in progress, embodied in the Apache Beam portability framework.

Stay tuned -- this is something that should be available relatively soon!

Comment: any update here? Can we clarify what runners are available for python sdk? I am leaving google cloud for a private cluster that has spark.

Answer (score 2):

Support for running Apache Beam Python pipelines has been added and there are some instructions on how to get started [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/spark/#portability).